# Spring MVC redirect to page with custom parameter when session expired

Tags: spring, session, redirect, session-timeout

I can not find any solutions for Spring to redirect to page together with parameters when session is timed out. I need to redirect to login page with error like *"Session expired"*. I have tried filter and method *session.isNew()*. But it does not work since when request reaches login page it always already has session. Also *HttpSessionEvent* handler does not work because does not allow to access to request attributes and redirect to page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create an Interceptor that adds the Refresh header to every response with a time just after session expiry.

```
public class RefreshInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle (
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, 
        Object handler, 
        ModelAndView modelAndView
    ) throws Exception {

      //if session != null and user is authenticated then...
      response.setIntHeader("Refresh", figureOutWhenSessionExpires() + A_SMALL_DELAY );

      super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);

    }
}
```

Comment: But this will not redirect me to anyway but prolong session. And this is not what I want.

Comment: @ovod it tells the browser to reload the current page just after session expires. If the page is secured, the server will redirect the browser to the login page